# can somebody tell me what went wrong, when I am trying to decrypt the ciphertext that I encrypted, it tells me that my padding is incorrect

Tags: python, encryption, aes, padding

when trying to decrypt my plaintext, it's giving me a value error.

```
mesg = b'b235dd55aae34e97a054b05c09777e18'

decipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_CBC,iv)
plaintext = decipher.decrypt(mesg)
truetext = unpad(plaintext,block_size=16)
print(hexa(truetext).decode())
```

the output says that

```
ValueError: Padding is incorrect.
```

even though I encrypted the plaintext myself using

```
plaintext = b"hello world"
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(pad(plaintext,16))
print(hexa(ciphertext).decode())
```

here is what my simple encryption/decryption looks like

```
#Pycryptodome
#unable to decrypt, padding problem
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
from binascii import hexlify as hexa


key = get_random_bytes(16)  
iv = get_random_bytes(16)
cipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_CBC,iv)

plaintext = b"hello world"
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(pad(plaintext,16))
print(hexa(ciphertext).decode())

mesg = b'b235dd55aae34e97a054b05c09777e18'

decipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_CBC,iv)
plaintext = decipher.decrypt(mesg)
truetext = unpad(plaintext,block_size=16)
print(hexa(truetext).decode())
```

Comment: You generate a random key and try to decrypt a harcorded (`mesg`) value with it. Try decrypting `ciphertext` instead of `mesg`

Comment: I wanted to see/try to decrypt a ciphertext that is already encoded. Im taking a class and wanted to try it, as a test run before actually doing it, seems like I might need to try the library the other guy is using.

Comment: In the start of your program you are generating a random key with `key = get_random_bytes(16)`. Each time you run your program you will get a new random key. To be able to decrypt a message, you need to use the same key for decryption, as you used when encrypting. As you hardcode the message you want to decrypt, and at the same time generate a new key, the hardcoded message can't be decrypted - as it was encrypted with another key from a previous run. You need to save the key used for encryption, so you have if for decryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code instead.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad, unpad
from binascii import hexlify as hexa


key = get_random_bytes(16)  
iv = get_random_bytes(16)
cipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_CBC,iv)

plaintext = b"hello world"
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(pad(plaintext,16))
print(hexa(ciphertext).decode())

# mesg = b'b235dd55aae34e97a054b05c09777e18' 
# can't be decrypted with different key/iv pair 

decipher = AES.new(key,AES.MODE_CBC,iv)
plaintext = decipher.decrypt(ciphertext)  # decrypt ciphertext instead
truetext = unpad(plaintext,block_size=16)
print(hexa(truetext).decode())
```

Your problem seems like(since i don't know key and iv of `msg`) is that when `msg` is decrypted and un-padded using `pkcs7` the padding is not correct since `pkcs7` check if message is padded correctly afterward (check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS)) and throws an error if message is not correctly padded.In summery, a `plaintext` encrypted with a specific key/iv pair, it's ciphertext must also be decrypted using same key/iv pair used during encryption otherwise your message will be decrypted to nonsense or result in wrong padding error.

Comment: Why recommend a different library without actually making it more secure? 1. You should make it clear that the IV should be generated during encryption and send along with the ciphertext. 2. Why don't you add authentication through AES-GCM or by adding a MAC?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I didn't mean to recommend a different library it's just because I'm used to ```cryptography``` module and didnt want to change mode since question is using CBC without MAC (didn't want to complicate things more). But i will edit to make things more clear that same key/iv pair must be used, I thought it's clear on last sentence, thank's .